# Benchmarking for DISK I/O Writes Per Second - ElasticSearch and MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance-monitoring, io, elasticsearch

During working on our project we needed to decide should we use "ElasticSearch" or "MySQL" to record the audit/trail logs of the system. Searching speed is not an issue here, we needed to see the disk I/O performance for both platforms. I had no experience of disk i/o monitoring, so after a little research I decided to monitor the writes per second for both ElasticSearch and MySQL via a simple load running script.

Should I consider writes per second for disk i/o performance ? Am I going in to the right direction ? Also, I'm not sure if less no. of writes per second is better or worst ?

Comment: There are many considerations to unpack. Your question unfortunately leads to more questions. How do you determine whether you've got a fair fight? Is this a single node Elasticsearch instance or multiple nodes? In your test, will you be sending enough data to overcome whatever write caching might come into play? Is Elasticsearch really the right tool for the job if maintaining a trustworthy audit trail is what's most important? ES is not ACID-compliant.